# Unable to find ip address of Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I actually want to connect rpi to my laptop without using any cables at all.So, I have written the raspbian image to a sd card..then added ssh and wpa_supplicant file with my wifi ssid and password in it.
Then I tried using the Advanced Ip scanner as well as the DHCP client table to get the Ip address.
But the raspberry pi is not detected here.
All help appreciated.
I am using windows 10 btw.

Comment: I'm not sure if that question is related to stackoverflow. But, anyway do you have access to your router? (usually the gateway sits on 10.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.1)

Comment: Get a keyboard and a screen on the Rasp.

Comment: @Yan I do have access to the router

Comment: @Gargi then you can log into your router's panel, go to the dhcp table and copy the rpi ip from there. If you don't know how to do it, comment your router's model and I'll try to help.

Comment: @Yan I have already checked the router's DHCP table..I can find my mobile and my laptop there..but no rpi..that is the original issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've typed in the SSID and pass correctly? Sounds stupid but I've made that mistake before.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that typing "ping raspberrypi" in the command line of your computer did not work, try the following:
If you don't have access to your router (or if the router solution does not work), you can use Hotspot. Your computer can share the internet connection via hotspot: take a note of the hotspot credentials and during the initialization of the PI (SD card with Rasbian OS), set up those credentials for connection. When booting, the PI will connect to your hostpot. In your laptop, you should then be able to see the device (and its IP) connected to your computer. You will than be able to connect via ssh to your PI and setup the original Wifi. Once this is done, run ifconfig to see the IP address the RasperryPi has on the Wifi and disable your hotspot. Hope that helps.